# Sort based on Frequency in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, frequency

Structure of input dataframe

```
ds= structure(list(MSISDN = c(800, 800, 783, 
975, 800)), .Names = "Number", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Need a simple output which looks like below (not able to add single break)

Num Freq

800 3

975 1

783 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Tabyl function from janitor package. It does the task that you want plus a bit more

```
library(janitor)
    ds <- structure(list(MSISDN = c(800, 800, 783,975, 800)), .Names = "Number", row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = "data.frame")

    tabyl(ds$Number)
```

Comment: It also gives you percentage to total in addition to total count that you want

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

**Base**

```
df <- data.frame(table(xx$Number))
df[rev(order(df$Freq)),]
```

**Result**

```
  #    Var1 Freq
  #    800    3
  #    975    1
  #    783    1
```

You can sort using `dplyr` as well.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(Freq))
```

**Data**

```
xx <- structure(list(MSISDN = c(800, 800, 783, 
975, 800)), .Names = "Number", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

using only dplyr

```
xx %>% group_by(Number) %>% summarise(Freq=n()) %>% arrange(desc(Freq))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, 
Can we display it as a percentage of total as to prop.table() does, by modifying your code above

Comment: @VaibhavSingh you can do that with this: `xx %>% group_by(Number) %>% summarise(Freq=n()) %>% arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% mutate (Per=Freq*100/nrow(xx))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `table` to get the frequencies, `sort` it in decreasing order and make with this a `data.frame`.

```
table(ds$Number) |> sort(TRUE) |> data.frame()  #Using pipes (since 4.1.0)
#data.frame(sort(table(ds$Number), TRUE))       #Traditional way
#  Var1 Freq
#1  800    3
#2  783    1
#3  975    1
```