# R: Sort data by most common value of a column

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I am following this stackoverflow post over here: [Sort based on Frequency in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883606/sort-based-on-frequency-in-r)

I am trying to sort my data by the most frequent value of the column "Node_A".

```
library(dplyr)

Data_I_Have <- data.frame(
   
    "Node_A" = c("John", "John", "John", "John, "John", "Peter", "Tim", "Kevin", "Adam", "Adam", "Xavier"),
    "Node_B" = c("Claude", "Peter", "Tim", "Tim", "Claude", "Henry", "Kevin", "Claude", "Tim", "Henry", "Claude"),
    " Place_Where_They_Met" = c("Chicago", "Boston", "Seattle", "Boston", "Paris", "Paris", "Chicago", "London", "Chicago", "London", "Paris"),
  "Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other" = c("10", "10", "1", "5", "2", "8", "7", "10", "3", "3", "5"),
  "What_They_Have_In_Common" = c("Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Computers", "Video Games", "Sports", "Movies", "Computers", "Sports", "Sports", "Video Games")
)

sort = Data_I_Have %>% arrange(Node_A, desc(Freq))
```

Could someone please show me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the last answer of the post you mentionend :

```
Data_I_Have %>% 
  group_by(Node_A) %>%
  arrange( desc(n()))

# Node_A Node_B X.Place_Where_They_Met Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other What_They_Have_In_Common
# <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                  <chr>                            <chr>                   
# 1  John   Claude Chicago                10                               Sports                  
# 2  John   Peter  Boston                 10                               Movies                  
# 3  John   Tim    Seattle                1                                Computers               
# 4  John   Tim    Boston                 5                                Computers               
# 5  John   Claude Paris                  2                                Video Games             
# 6  Peter  Henry  Paris                  8                                Sports                  
# 7  Tim    Kevin  Chicago                7                                Movies                  
# 8  Kevin  Claude London                 10                               Computers               
# 9  Adam   Tim    Chicago                3                                Sports                  
# 10 Adam   Henry  London                 3                                Sports                  
# 11 Xavier Claude Paris                  5                                Video Games
```

Answer (score 2):

Before sorting the data you need to count the data. You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

Data_I_Have %>%
  count(Node_A, sort = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(Data_I_Have, by = 'Node_A')

#   Node_A n Node_B X.Place_Where_They_Met Years_They_Have_Known_Each_Other What_They_Have_In_Common
#1    John 5 Claude                Chicago                               10                   Sports
#2    John 5  Peter                 Boston                               10                   Movies
#3    John 5    Tim                Seattle                                1                Computers
#4    John 5    Tim                 Boston                                5                Computers
#5    John 5 Claude                  Paris                                2              Video Games
#6    Adam 2    Tim                Chicago                                3                   Sports
#7    Adam 2  Henry                 London                                3                   Sports
#8   Kevin 1 Claude                 London                               10                Computers
#9   Peter 1  Henry                  Paris                                8                   Sports
#10    Tim 1  Kevin                Chicago                                7                   Movies
#11 Xavier 1 Claude                  Paris                                5              Video Games
```

Or we can use `add_count` instead of `count` so that we don't have to join the data.

```
Data_I_Have %>% add_count(Node_A, sort = TRUE)
```

You can remove the `n` column from the final output if it is not needed.